# How to resize my image taken from internal storage before updating to Firebase cloud?

Tags: android, firebase, image, file-upload

This is the logic where i take the picture from gallery/camera and I upload it to firebase cloud.
I take other informations from another EditText and i checked if they i can upload or not.

```
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nume, pret,cantitate, categorie;
                nume = etNume.getText().toString().trim();
                pret = etPret.getText().toString().trim();
                cantitate = etCantitate.getText().toString().trim();
                categorie = etCategorie.getText().toString().trim();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(nume)){
                    etNume.setError("Email is required.");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pret)){
                    etPret.setError("Email is required.");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(cantitate)){
                    etCantitate.setError("Email is required.");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(categorie)){
                    etCategorie.setError("Email is required.");
                    return;
                }
                StorageReference file = mStorageRef.child("Produs").child(nume + ".jpg");
                UploadTask uploadTask= file.putFile(mImage);
                Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                            throw task.getException();
                        }

                        return file.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Uri downloadUri =task.getResult();
                            path = downloadUri.toString();
                            Produs p=new Produs(nume,pret,cantitate,path,categorie);
                            Task task1 =mDatabase.child("Produs").child(nume).setValue(p);
                            task1.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Add.this, "Produsul a fost adaugat cu succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                                }
                            });

                            task1.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Add.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

How can i upload my code to resize my image(taken from gallery/camera) to size 700X1000?

Answer (score 0):

1 - First create a Bitmap from your URI/Path :

2 - After that, you can resize it (e.g. 700x1000):

```
  private static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    }
```

3 - Save the resized bitmap to your device as a file and keep the path.

4 - Now upload it to the Firebase Cloud.